# IoT network traffic generation

Tags: networking, routes, iot, network-traffic

I need to generate IoT network traffic, for example, traffic  from many webcams, or smartTVs. Potentially, each device can have different behaviour, but should have something in common. e.g. at each home smartTV is activated in different times, have software updates in different times etc. But, all (or many) smartTVs will have something in common, - ports/ destinations, packet sizes etc.

If it helps, I can sniff short streams of say, webcam, when its on, when it uploads data etc. and I need a tool that will use this to generate traffic from 1000 webcams, with different disributions.

I looked at gns3 and ostinato, but I'm not sure this is what I need.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question bu still someone could still be looking for an answer so: I've been using the tool [here](http://www.grid.unina.it/software/ITG/). It's pretty simple and it may help solving your problem. Just adjust the various traffic characteristics to emulate IoT devices.